# Clear canvas area with special bitmap's form

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, draw

I develop a drawing application and I need to implement eraser tool to clear special areas of pictures. Eraser must erase some circle area unevenly. It means - only center of circle should be erased completely and edges of circle should be erased partially, with alpha.

To achieve this behaviour I created the image that representes eraser's figure

[image]

Then, to erase some area of view, I draw the eraser's figure above some picture like this:

```
private val picture: Bitmap
  private val bgPaint = Paint()
  private var eraser: Bitmap

  private val eraserPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
    val mode: PorterDuff.Mode = PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT
    xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(mode)
    color = Color.TRANSPARENT
    alpha = 0
  }

  init {
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inMutable = true
    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.petushara, options)
    eraser = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.eraser, options)
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, bgPaint)
  }

  override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas)
    canvas.drawBitmap(picture, 0f, 0f, bgPaint)
    canvas.drawBitmap(eraser, 100f, 300f, eraserPaint)
  }
```

This is whole my view-class, excluding constructors. I expect that area of picture will be erased by figure of eraser, but it erases by figure of square like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found out the solution. Write code like this:

```
  private val picture: Bitmap
  private val bgPaint = Paint()
  private var eraser: Bitmap

  private val eraserPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
    val mode: PorterDuff.Mode = PorterDuff.Mode.XOR
    xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(mode)
  }

  init {
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inMutable = true
    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.petushara, options)
    eraser = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.eraser, options)
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, bgPaint)
  }

  override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas)
    canvas.drawBitmap(picture, 0f, 0f, bgPaint)
    canvas.drawBitmap(eraser, 100f, 300f, eraserPaint)
  }
```

Then result picture looks like my expectations:

[image]

Comment: Actually, this i not best solution. If you will try erase area which already was erased, this area will be colorized by erase-image color. Black in our case